# How do I assign this gameobject unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I want to assign the two game objects to two different canvases so I can switch between the two, but there is no option

[Image of the scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai6Yj.png)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class displayManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public static GameObject LevelSelector;
    [SerializeField] public static GameObject MainMenu;

    public static void OpenSelector()
    {
        Debug.Log("opened settings ");
        LevelSelector.SetActive(true);
        MainMenu.SetActive(false);
    }

    public static void CloseSelector()
    {
        Debug.Log("Settings menu closed");
        LevelSelector.SetActive(false);
        MainMenu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I think it's something to do with the variables being static but when they are I can't access them inside the function for the `OpenSettings()` and the `CloseSettings()`

Comment: remove the "static"

Comment: i did that but ot just says i cannot acseess ther non-static member

Comment: Is it necessary to declare "static" to the function as well? Only variables that declare "static" can be used within a function that declares "static". Please remove "static" from the function and try it.

Comment: that worked tysm